# Redirecting all output to file in Julia

Tags: io, julia

I would like to know how to redirect any output of a given call to a file, so that this file contains exactly what would have normally been displayed into the REPL.

I know that the package [Suppressor.jl](https://github.com/JuliaIO/Suppressor.jl) is an interesting entry point and does *almost* what I need, but for instance:

```
using DataFrames
using Suppressor
output = @capture_out begin
dtf = DataFrame(                 
 [8.04   9.14  7.46   6.58;    
  6.95   8.14  6.77   5.76;   
  8.33   9.26  7.81   8.47])
dtf
end
```

captures nothing (or more precisely, it captures `""`) in output. To be able to capture the output, we have to write `print(dtf)` instead of `dtf` in this code block (while the simple `dtf` instruction would actually produce an output in the REPL). So it seems that any output cannot be captured by this macro `@capture_out`.

Actually, when I send a given code block to Julia, I would need to redirect to a given file all that would be displayed in the console: either normal output or error messages.

What would be the best / easiest way to achieve that? And, if possible, with minimal dependencies on packages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you are facing is described in the docstring of `display`:

> In general, you cannot assume that display output goes to `stdout` (unlike `print(x)` or `show(x)`). For example, display(x) may open up a separate window with an image. `display(x)` means "show x in the best way you can for the current output device(s)." If you want REPL-like text output that is guaranteed to go to stdout, use `show(stdout, "text/plain", x)` instead.

And the problem is that if you just write `dtf` the output is displayed using `display`.

Unfortunately I cannot recommend a simple work-around of this behavior (you could e.g. modify the destination where the `display` sends its output but then you will get also e.g. terminal escape sequences which I assume you do not want).

For instance Documenter.jl needs to intercept the output to test the REPL results and what it does is quite complex unfortunately, as you can check [here](https://github.com/JuliaDocs/Documenter.jl/blob/master/src/DocTests.jl#L225).

Maybe there are better solutions, but the simplest one is to do what `display` documentation recommends, i.e. use `show(stdout, "text/plain", x)` instead (and just replace `stdout` with a custom stream).

For instance [here](https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl/blob/main/test/io.jl) you can check how we test output in DataFrames.jl.

PS. If you want to pass a `Matrix` to `DataFrame` constructor and want to generate column names automatically add `:auto` argument for column names, as `DataFrame` docsting explains:

> It is also allowed to pass a vector of vectors or a matrix as as the first argument. In this case the second argument must be a vector of `Symbol`s or strings specifying column names, or the symbol `:auto` to generate column names `x1`, `x2`, ... automatically.

#### EDIT

If you need to run external code blocks and fetch their output then the task is simpler. The only assumption is that these code blocks do not use `display` explicitly (which is unlikely). In this case just use e.g. Suppresor.jl and wrap whole code block in `print` like this:

```
julia> output = @capture_out print(begin
       println("Hello")
       dtf = DataFrame(                 
        [8.04   9.14  7.46   6.58;    
         6.95   8.14  6.77   5.76;   
         8.33   9.26  7.81   8.47], :auto)
       dtf
       end)
"Hello\n3×4 DataFrame\n Row │ x1       x2       x3       x4\n     │ Float64  Float64  Float64  Float64\n─────┼────────────────────────────────────\n   1 │    8.04     9.14     7.46     6.58\n   2 │    6.95     8.14     6.77     5.76\n   3 │    8.33     9.26     7.81     8.47"

julia> println(output)
Hello
3×4 DataFrame
 Row │ x1       x2       x3       x4
     │ Float64  Float64  Float64  Float64
─────┼────────────────────────────────────
   1 │    8.04     9.14     7.46     6.58
   2 │    6.95     8.14     6.77     5.76
   3 │    8.33     9.26     7.81     8.47
```

in this way you fetch both all what is printed to `stdout` within the block and the value of last expression gets `print`ed (or `show`n - whatever you would prefer).

As commented this will work correctly unless `display` is called by the user within the block but it is unlikely as `display` is normally not used explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for this very complete answer! However, I still struggle with this part: "use `show(stdout, "text/plain", x)` instead (and just replace `stdout` with a custom stream)". I know very little about I/O in Julia, but I expected that something like that would work: `show(open("myfile.txt", "w"), "text/plain", dtf)`. Instead, it just creates an empty file. How can we specify this custom stream then? (Also, as I understand it, there is no universal simple way in Julia to capture any result as a string, which looks odd for the R-user I am :-) I would just need an equivalent of `sink()` in R.)

Comment: (And a complement to my question. When you suggested to use `show`, maybe you suggested actually to modify the code block itself, which is impossible for my purpose. Actually, my goal is to retrieve/read existing, external Julia code blocks, and write sequentially their REPL output into files. Thus, this should be made without modifying the code blocks themselves. I should also have said that explicitly.)

Comment: Regarding `show` - you need to close `"myfile.txt"`. The simplest thing to do is to `open("myfile.txt") do io show(io, "text/plain", dtf) end`. Regarding the external code blocks: this is actually a simpler task then - I will comment in an answer.

Comment: Many thanks, this is very clear and helpful!